# array input text get value

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

i want to get input text value of array in javascript

this is my code :

```
Item : <input id="t_item" name="t_item[]" type="text" class="teks3">
Cost : <input id="t_cost" name="t_cost[]" type="text" class="teks3">
<input type="button" id="tb_more_item" class="add_file"/>
```

and the js code is :

```
$("input#tb_more_item").click(function(){
   var new_file = $("
      Item : <input id='t_item' name='t_item[]' type='text' class='teks3'/>&nbsp;
      Cost : <input id='t_cost' name='t_cost[]' type='text' class='teks3'/>&nbsp;
   ");

   $("div#div_item").append(new_file).fadeIn();
});
```

i try to get more item value with this code :

```
var item_value = [], cost_value = [];

$("input#t_item").each(function() {
   $thisItem = $(this);
   item_value = $thisItem.val();
});
$("input#t_cost").each(function() {
   $thisCost = $(this);
   cost_value = $thisCost.val();
});

alert(item_value +"-"+ cost_value );
```

the result is get the last value value i've typed in the input text.

does anyone have the solutions?

thanks

Comment: but there are no errors found.. can you solve it? how to get the input text array value?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating invalid html by appending elements with duplicate ids.  Update the .each() selectors to use the name attribute instead.

Also, inside the .each() functions you are overwriting the array variables with the value of the current item - that is, the array gets thrown away and replaced with the value, which is why that variable holds only the last value after the .each() finishes. What you want to do is add the value of each input as a separate element in the array:

```
$('input[name="t_item\\[\\]"]').each(function() {
   item_value.push(this.value);
});
```

And similar for t_cost.

Comment: this code cannot solve the problem, it still cannot get the previous value of text input..